# Как изменить вид домена сайта при выдаче запросов?

Tags: seo, домен, поисковые-системы

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при выдаче сайт вместо http://enotlandia.ru/  выглядел http://www.enotlandia.ru/ . Пробовала в Гугле изменить на основную, но ничего не вышло и sitemap не обновляется. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

1. Нужно сделать 301 редирект с http://enotlandia.ru/* на http://www.enotlandia.ru/$1
2. Нужно в файле robots.txt указать Host http://www.enotlandia.ru/
3. Нужно зайти в кабинет вебмастера (гугл, яндекс) и выбрать основной домен

Answer (score 0):

Примените линк canonical `<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.enotlandia.ru" />`. [Инфо Гугл](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=ru).